# How can I add an image to the comment section?

Tags: support, comments

Yesterday, I asked [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327951/how-to-safely-remove-previously-installed-version-of-web-browsersor-any-softwar).

Couple of people replied to me. But with the last answer, I need to post an image of terminal screenshot in `add comment` section to get more information.

How can I do that? Or I shall opt for `Answer Your Question` and start with mentioning user-name of previous commenter?

Comment: You can edit your own post, you know? ;)

Answer (score 5):

The way Ask Ubuntu works is by editing your question, not doing a back and forth in the comments. That way it's easier for the next person to understand what the problem is without having to dig through post after post of explanation.

From looking at your question it seems you've already figured that out. :)